# Why do inductors release a high voltage when disconnected

Tags: inductor, electromagnetism, inductance, inductive

I take a 12 volt battery, take a strong electromagnet, and fire it up.

I then touch the two terminals that are currently connected, one terminal of the battery, and one terminal of the electromagnet.

When I disconnect the terminal of the electromagnet to one terminal of the battery, while still placing my thumb over the terminal of the electromagnet and the battery, I receive a little shock.

I know that the inductor releases a higher voltage when disconnected, but why?

•The magnetic field is induced with an inductor with X amount of turns when the battery is connected.

• The battery is now released, and the magnetic field closes down, and induces a current on the inductor with X amount of turns.

Heres where I am confused- both X's are the same amount of turns, therefore a 1 to 1 ratio. Why are different voltages present with the same voltage source, a 12 volt battery?

Answer (score 8):

Changing currents in an inductor result in changes of magnetic flux in the inductor. Then, since the flux changed, the induced voltage changes. That is why

\$v = L{di \over dt} \$

Thus, when you disconnect the inductor, the current changes from whatever it was to 0 in a very short amount of time. The resulting \${di \over dt} \$ becomes very large making the induced voltage very large.

Comment: The formula has a - in front of it to indicate that it's in the opposite direction.It is a minor matter however.

Answer (score 0):

When you disconnect the battery, the magnetic field of inductor will collapse. This collapsing magnetic field will produce current. However since the circuit is open, the moving electrons (current) has no where to go but to accumulate on the open end of the circuit, therefore producing high voltage. Thats the little shock you sensed.

Comment: The electrons don't accumulate - unless you think there is some capacitance. Read Justin's answer. You will find that your posts will be taken much more seriously if you use proper capitalisation as it improves readability and gives a much more favourable impression of the author.

Comment: It is sometimes convenient to think of inductors giving electrons innertia. it removes the need to consider the magnetic field.  and in the real world there is always some capacitance involved.

Answer (score 0):

An inductor (L) always has a parasitic capacitance (C) across its two sides--basically due to the wiring and the switch to the inductor.  This inductor/capacitor becomes an oscillating LC circuit with energy oscillating between that of a magnetic field (current in the inductor) and an electric field (voltage across the inductor).  Make everything superconducting so as to avoid somewhat immaterial effects of resistance for the argument.  With initial conditions of some current I_0 already flowing in the inductor (and an unimportant charge Q_0 on the capacitor), the switch is opened.  Before the spark occurs, a large current/voltage oscillation between the two sides of the inductor is set up having a huge angular frequency omega = 1/sqrt(LC).  With no way to spark across the two ends and no resistance in the circuit, the amplitude of the oscillations continues with energy 1/2 LI^2 + 1/2 CV^2 conserved.  This expression relates the amplitude of the voltage oscillation to the initial conditions (almost all from I_0) and leads to a very large peak voltage V_p = L omega I_0.  The oscillation causes the voltage on the switch to grow toward the peak voltage, but before hitting that peak, it hits the voltage necessary for breakdown and a spark occurs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).